# Script to find and create missing indexes of the schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I use the below script to find missing indexes but there is any modification on it to find and create statement of index creation or to find which column we can index with ?

Database: Postgres

```
SELECT 
relname AS TableName
,seq_scan-idx_scan AS TotalSeqScan
,CASE WHEN seq_scan-idx_scan > 0 
    THEN 'Missing Index Found' 
    ELSE 'Missing Index Not Found' 
END AS MissingIndex
,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relname::regclass)) AS TableSize
,idx_scan AS TotalIndexScan
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE schemaname='public'
AND pg_relation_size(relname::regclass)>100000 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that that query is not very useful.

Better is

```
SELECT relname,
       seq_scan,
       seq_tup_read / seq_scan AS tup_per_scan
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE seq_scan > 0;
```

An index is missing if both the second and third column are big.

Comment: it gives me error >>> [42703] ERROR: column "seq_scan" does not exist Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pg_stat_user_indexes.idx_scan". Position: 25

Comment: I tried this and worked for me : 
select relname,idx_scan,idx_tup_read/idx_scan AS tup_per_scan
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes
where idx_scan > 0

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `pg_stat_user_tables` rather than `pg_stat_user_indexes`. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the query, is there any way to find the column name that has to be indexed in the tables?

Comment: @SurjeetChaurasia You use `pg_stat_statements` for that, it is the king's way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything in "pg_stat_all_tables" can tell you what columns of the table might be missing from an index. I'd generally recommend a slow query log ([auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html)) to identify queries that might need indexes, rather than pg_stat_all_tables to identify tables that might. The nature of the query will then often make the column obvious. If you want to see if a specific index would be used, you can try [hypopg](https://github.com/HypoPG/hypopg), but you need to nominate the columns, it won't choose them for you.